# is there a difference between the jquery code here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Here is the code block a

```
$('ul.filter li').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(e) { //do something });
});
```

Here is code block b

```
$('ul.filter li').click(function(e) { //do something });
```

Don't these do the same thing? is one better than the other? Which one is the better/faster method?
I would assume block b since it has less code but I want to confirm it here, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The effect you see will be the same, but in the first case, every `li` element is assigned a new function, as you are creating the function object inside the `each` callback.

In the second case, there exists only one copy of the event handler, which means it uses less memory over all (although this is probably not measurable).

Internally, [`click` calls `on`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/event.js#L1017) (in jQuery 1.7), which is [iterating over the elements via `each` as well](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/event.js#L913):

```
return this.each( function() {
    jQuery.event.add( this, types, fn, data, selector );
});
```

This is the case with many jQuery methods (most often noted in the documentation), so you are saving characters and memory by letting jQuery implicitly do this.

Comment: Probably someone without clue who thinks he has clue, has happened to me before :) While there are many minor differences, the major difference is a new function created for every element +1

Answer (score 2):

They would both have the same effect.

I would prefer the second only because it is more concise and you're creating a single anonymous function to handle the click rather than an anonymous function per element.

Answer (score 1):

For Jquery philosophy, the second is better because it is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Both are more or less same and give the same results. The second code snippet will also internally run `each` loop and assign the click handler to each `li` element.

But yes the second code snippet is very clear and simple.

Comment: strictly the second snippet will assign the _exact same_ click handler to each element, whereas the first creates a new (but identical) function for each element.  The second is therefore more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The second usage is called "implicit iteration" and is one of the cornerstones of jQuery.

For example, in JavaScript Definitive Guide, 6th Ed, p.530 for jQuery Basics:

> Despite the power of the each() method, it is not very commonly used,
>   since jQuery methods usually iterate implicitly over the set of
>   matched elements and operate on them all. You typically only need to
>   use each() if you need to manipulate the matched elements in
>   different ways. Even then, you may not need to call each(), since a
>   number of jQuery methods allow you to pass a callback function.

in http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics

> Implicit iteration means that jQuery automatically iterates over all
>   the elements in a selection when you call a setter method on that
>   selection. This means that, when you want to do something to all of
>   the elements in a selection, you don't have to call a setter method on
>   every item in your selection — you just call the method on the
>   selection itself, and jQuery iterates over the elements for you.

Typically, when the library has this built-in as the standard way of doing it, it will be in general better and faster, or else they wouldn't have built it in.